# wagtail collectstatic is failing

Tags: django, wagtail, collectstatic

I'm using python 3.7 , wagtail 2.10

After:

python manage.py collectstatic

I have the errors below.
My insite about the issue is that there is a Django related problem about
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'
The files not founded must be used by Django admin.

Can't figured out until now how to solve the problem.

```
    Post-processing 'bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.min.css' failed!
```

...

```
    File "/home/mihai/env_wagtail2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 93, in hashed_name

    raise ValueError("The file '%s' could not be found with %r." % (filename, self))

    ValueError: The file 'bootstrap3/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot' could not be found with       

    <django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7fa45bdc5160>.
```

Comment: Did you verify that `bootstrap3/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot` does indeed exist?

Comment: It sounds silly but I did not verify because I was sure it is not the problem because I use bootstrap 4. I have an old bs3 folder which lacks of the file above. I corrected and now, collectstatic reports missing another files which surely exists:

Comment: Post-processing 'site1/css/about.css' failed!
ValueError: The file 'site1/css/'../img/jeremy-thomas-E0AHdsENmDg-unsplash.jpg' could not be found with <django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7f804b27e198>. Your suggestion was write, I have made a step but still not find the error. Searching now.